# How can I get UV Index via API?

Tags: yahoo-weather-api

Yahoo's desktop weather reports UV index but I can't find that information via the API. Am I doing something wrong?

select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='brooklyn, ny')

... so I'm asking for everything.